# What test can I do to determine a malfunctioning E bike motor?

Tags: motor

It's gonna take a while to get a replacement controller module from China so I thought I could do some tests to determine what is not functioning properly.

Info: 3 phase brushless motor, 36volt rated controller, cutoff 30volts.

It's a typical set up, 3 wires to power the motor, 3 wires to get hall effect sensor state, 2 additional wires to power the hall effect transistors.

The problem: Suddenly the motor lost power and makes a loud noise suddenly. Then within a few seconds power dies as if the controller is preventing a short or something. You have to kill the throttle and hit it again for it to turn the motor again until it dies again.

I was told that disconnecting the hall sensors would still allow the motor to run, at a stand still without the sensors connected when I hit the throttle it creates a magnetic lock the wheel is frozen in place.

Opening the motor and inspecting everything mechanically speaking seems sound.
Power drain is minimal from the li-ion battery dips only 3 volts under full load to the motor. The failure is predictable there is nothing random like a short so I can reproduce the tests as needed. Maybe it is just a blown capacitor, maybe a blown hall sensor. If I can pin point it by testing then I can perhaps repair the sensors or its module.

What tests can I make to narrow the problem to find out what has failed exactly?

I have a multimeter but no scope.

Comment: 1. Compare load test with no load test behavior. ( driving wheel jacked up) Does it fault immediately? or affected by a thermal delay according to load and acceleration rate.  2. Try to measure current by voltage drop on ground cable in mV and use to determine if there is cross conduction losses and heat dissipation.  10% drop in LiPo cells at 100 SoC is rather large. Check cell balance under constant load or charge. It should be <1% voltage under load otherwise an indication of rapid aging.

Comment: @Tony Stewart I tried to test with the motor without the wheel just on a flipped over fork and it dies in the same manner. It takes about 6 seconds give or take to fail. Also, you have to turn the motor a bit before it can start turning again. There is warm spot in the battery pack but that is a problem for another question.

Comment: There may be a burnt winding in the motor with partial short circuit. You can test this when you disconnect the motor and use it as generator moved by hand. An AC voltmeter between any two of the three wires should give you the same voltage at the same rotation speed. Or connect a small 6V bulb and compare the brightness.